# Reject emails from a subdomain in Exim4

Tags: linux, email, exim

Is it possible in Exim4 to reject emails sent to a subdomain, eg sub.example.com?

A user has started a loop that is sending too many emails to the server, which generates the error "refused: too many connections".

Or is it possible to temporarily reject for a specific email address, eg new-task@sub.example.com?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that with the ACL rule file, located `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` or `/etc/exim4.conf`

Here would be your ACL rule file:

```
acl_check_rcpt:
  ...
  # Reject all mail to sub.example.com
  deny domain       = *.sub.example.com
       message      = This subdomain is not accepting email.
```

and if you want to reject a specific mail address:

```
acl_check_rcpt:
  ...
  # Reject mail for new-task@sub.example.com
  deny local_parts  = new-task
       domain       = sub.example.com
       message      = This email address is not accepting email.
  ...
```

then restart `sudo service exim4 restart`